# If 'highcharts-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am using highcharts-angular as per official documentation : https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular and facing the error :

> If 'highcharts-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Answer (score 1):

After browsing through no of pages, problem solved when,

> I disabled Angular language service and restarting my editor.

for more info : https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/120#issuecomment-638128725